# Can I make an item in a YUI menu that is NOT a menu item

Tags: yui, yui-menu

I have a [YUI menu](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/) top bar navigation menu based from [this example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/topnavfrommarkup_source.html).

I'd like to be able to insert items to it that serve as captions and not menu items. For instance I may have a list of products in different categories, and I want a category heading for each. I don't want submenus - I want headings WITHIN the menu.

I was hoping it was as simple as doing this :

```
 <li class="menuHeading">Heading</li>
```

(and obviously defining the `menuHeading` style).

This actually works - insomuch as the item appears in the menu in the correct position. But it behaves as a menu item (highlights in blue when I rollover it). I inspected the DOM in Chrome and it appears that the YUI menu javascript is actually adding the following class `'yuimenuitem'` and giving it a generated ID.

Is there an 'official' way to do what I want or do I have to resort to some hack, I'm thinking just changing the `menuHeading` class to have a white background when I hover over it, but I'd rather not do that if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YUI Menu has support for headings built in - they're called group titles.  There are two YUI Menu examples that illustrate how to title groups:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/example05.html
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/menu/example06.html